# Local Playback Security setting in Flash for outside communication with inside as-classes?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, networking, local, playback

I'm using external actionscript files located in the root of my webfolder, 
but I also want to communicate with another website.

How should I set my Local playback in publish settings?
Access Local Only? or Access Network Only?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i remember if an swf file is located on a webserver it knows it's in the internet (so it has problems with loading files from the web if saved on users' hdd if it isn't allowed in the Global Security Settings panel) - so imho it should be published for web